# Mysql using monthname with month

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get the name of the Month through Monthname, but it just returns `(NULL)`

`Date = 4`

`MONTHNAME(str_to_date(Month(Date), '%m'))`

Comment: you could CAST Date AS STRING

Answer (score 2):

As per MySQL's [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_monthname), you can use `MONTHNAME` function directly on `date` column, e.g.:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(Date);
```

This would give you the required result.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(1, '%m'));//returns January
```

Also read this [Documentation](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-monthname-function.php)